# How QTP is able to call native functions of application in java

Tags: automation, swt, qtp

I want to know how QTP is able to call java functions of application under test.What are the technology by which this can be possible.
Any how QTP may be getting pure java object of windows,buttons,etc from runtime instance of AUT.I just want to know that how it is possible.
Can I get all runtime objects from javaw process or from JVM.

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks In Advance

Comment: Actually it isn't possible, QTP uses magic.

Comment: Yeah. Because it only calls Java functions located outside of the JVM.